Why is getBBox() returning {x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0} for visible SVG elements in React?
Here's my SVG:
<svg width="663" height="576" viewBox="0 0 663 576" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<rect id="misa" width="663" height="576" fill="#D9D9D9"/>
</svg>

And here is my React component:
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import hillstateSvg from "./images/B.svg"; // SVG file path

const escapeCssSelector = (id) => {
  return `#${CSS.escape(id)}`;
};

const App = () => {
  const canvasRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(hillstateSvg)
      .then((response) => response.text())
      .then((data) => {
        const parser = new DOMParser();
        const svgDoc = parser.parseFromString(data, "image/svg+xml");
        const svgElement = svgDoc.documentElement;
        const canvas = canvasRef.current;
        const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        // Set canvas size to match SVG size
        const svgWidth = parseInt(svgElement.getAttribute("width"));
        const svgHeight = parseInt(svgElement.getAttribute("height"));
        canvas.width = svgWidth;
        canvas.height = svgHeight;

        console.log(`Canvas size set to width: ${svgWidth}, height: ${svgHeight}`);

        const svgString = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svgElement);
        const img = new Image();
        const svgBlob = new Blob([svgString], { type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8" });
        const url = URL.createObjectURL(svgBlob);

        img.onload = () => {
          ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
          URL.revokeObjectURL(url);

          console.log("Image loaded and drawn on canvas");

          // Add blue dots
          const ids = ["misa", "misa2"];
          ids.forEach((id) => {
            const targetElement = svgElement.querySelector(escapeCssSelector(id));
            if (targetElement) {
              const bbox = targetElement.getBBox();
              if (bbox.width === 0 || bbox.height === 0) {
                // Try getBoundingClientRect if getBBox returns invalid dimensions
                const rect = targetElement.getBoundingClientRect();
                if (rect.width === 0 || rect.height === 0) {
                  console.log(`Element with ID: ${id} has invalid dimensions.`);
                  return;
                } else {
                  console.log(`Element ID: ${id}, rect:`, rect);
                  const cx = rect.left + rect.width / 2;
                  const cy = rect.top + rect.height / 2;
                  ctx.beginPath();
                  ctx.arc(cx, cy, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
                  ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
                  ctx.fill();
                  console.log("Blue dot drawn using getBoundingClientRect");
                }
              } else {
                const cx = bbox.x + bbox.width / 2;
                const cy = bbox.y + bbox.height / 2;
                console.log(`Element ID: ${id}, bbox:`, bbox);
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.arc(cx, cy, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
                ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
                ctx.fill();
                console.log("Blue dot drawn using getBBox");
              }
            } else {
              // Log if the element with the ID is not found
              console.log(`Element with ID: ${id} not found.`);
            }
          });
        };

        img.onerror = () => {
          console.error("Failed to load the image.");
        };

        img.src = url;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error fetching or parsing the SVG file:", error);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <h1>SVG Element Click Coordinates</h1>
        <canvas ref={canvasRef} className="canvas-container"></canvas>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;

The console outputs the following messages indicating that the elements misa and  are found, but their dimensions are invalid:
I'm using getBBox() to calculate the position of the elements. I've also tried using getBoundingClientRect(), but it also returns dimensions of 0.
How can I correctly get the dimensions and positions of these SVG elements to draw the blue dots on the canvas?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
debugging

You'd have to attach the svg to a document that's rendered.

Your svg is parsed but not rendered. You can retrieve dimensions from the rect's x, y, width and height attributes. See example codepen

This related post may help "Any other ways to obtain the values of svg's bounding-rect". In short: you can only to some extent emulate getBBox in a headless/non-rendered environment by calculating x/y extremes from the geometry of elements. Dimensions set via CSS, <text> elements and transformations are hard to emulate - I'm not aware of any library that solves these issues. But maybe someone is working on it.
